# Speeding up Com Interop calls by using unmanaged c++ on an interop object

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, office-interop, com-interop

Please can anyone shed light on this.

I have a program that uses the outlook interop assemblies, part of this is quite slow, and I would like to use native unmanaged c++ to manipulate the com object(s) for some more intensive work.

inline Microsoft::Office::Interop::Outlook::_Application^ OutlookApp()
        {
            return dynamic_cast(HostApplication);
        }

What I would like to do is pass the above returned outlook object from that routine maybe with manipulation or pinning to an unmanaged c++ routine and then manipulate it as the underlying native com object so i get the speed of unmanaged com.  I am wondering how this could be done, or would this get marshalled back and forth even more than in managed c++.

Is this even possible and if so how, or is there something I do not understand about the concept and interop?

Comment: It is a pointless micro-optimization.  Office apps are out-of-process servers.  Making an interop call is pretty expensive, it always requires a thread context switch plus the cost of serializing the function arguments and returning the function result.  Tens of thousands of cpu cycles.  Nobody can see your ~1% perf improvement.  If you want to do this faster then you have to write an add-in.  Code that runs inside the Office process and therefore can avoid the cost of having to bridge the process boundary.

Answer (score 0):

It's the process boundaries I assume managed c++ is still not in process to office apps.  Therefore still pretty slow.  Looks like a good reason to use Delphi.

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to use native unmanaged c++ to manipulate the com object(s) for some more intensive work

But you don't use unmanaged C++, instead C++/CLI (managed C++) is used:

```
 Microsoft::Office::Interop::Outlook::_Application^ OutlookApp() 
 { 
     return dynamic_cast(HostApplication); 
 }
```

If you need to avoid using .net framework I'd suggest developing unmanaged COM add-in which implements the IDTExtensibility2 interface or standalone application.